# dart, a nicer way of mapping maps?

Tags: dictionary, dart

I like the `.map((item){/*mapper*/})` that is on the `Iterable` classes, but the `Map` class doesn't appear to implement an analogous method. When I want to do the following, I have to create an blank instance and then `forEach` over the existing `Map` I want to `map` to the new instance type:

```dart
void noSuchMethod(Invocation inv){
  if(inv.isMethod){
    var namedArguments = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    inv.namedArguments.forEach((k, v){
      namedArguments[MirrorSystem.getName(k)] = v;
    });
    return;
  }
  super.noSuchMethod(inv);
}
```

Is there a nicer way of mapping `Map`s? It seems a litle odd that there is a `forEach((v){})` for `Iterable`s and a `forEach((k, v){})` for `Map`s but not a `map((k, v){})` for `Map`s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```dart
Map m = {'1': 1, '2':2 };
var newMap = new Map.fromIterable(m.keys, key: (k) => k , value: (v) => m[v] * 5 );
```

Comment: thanks that's great, I'll use this for now, it would still be nice to have a `map((k, v){})` method for `Map`s though.

Comment: You should create a feature request on dartbug.com then (if there isn't already). If you do post the link here so people know where to find it and can star.

Comment: @DanielRobinson It's late but there is now. For example
`newmap = oldmap.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value));`
is the same as `newmap = oldmap`. I am not sure if the object is the same.

Answer (score 28):

*Just for info*

Now you can use a special method that is in every instance of the Map class.

```
final dict = { "id": 1, "name": "Alex", "isAdmin": true };
// A simple map, that contains a user's info

dict.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value.toString()));
// Here we can transform the key and the value of this map

print(dict);
// { "id": "1", "name": "Alex", "isAdmin": "true" }
// All fields are strings now
```

Comment: Perfect!  This is much more analogous to List.map() than the other proposed solutions, and much more succinct.

Comment: For a more complete example, I created the following gist: https://gist.github.com/rickbsgu/6af051158fd4c32fff188b3256c7e705.  You can paste it into dartpad to see it work.

Answer (score 9):

Since Dart SDK 2.2.1, you can use the [collection for](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_for_elements_to_map_fromIterable.html) syntax. This works for maps as well as [lists](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#collection-if) ([docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators)).

Example:

```dart
Map m = {'1': 1, '2':2 };

final newMap = {
  for (var k in m.keys)
    k: m[k] * 5,
};
```